# reading a particular line from a file in bash script using variable as line number

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a csv file which contains a large number of entries. I have to read certain lines from the file. The line number is stored in a variable called *lineno*.
How to accomplish this?It may look something like:

```
line=$(sed -n "($lineno)p")
```

I want to know the correct syntax to do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You pretty much have it.

```
line=$(sed -n "${lineno}p" "$file")
```